# Increasing code cache capacity no ends

Tags: android, url

While running, i get this in my android monitor, it keeps expanding with no ends :

```
09-02 14:01:36.150 25666-25671/... I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=27KB
09-02 14:01:36.150 25666-25671/... I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=30KB, data=27KB
09-02 14:01:36.151 25666-25671/... I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
09-02 14:01:39.064 25666-25671/... I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=59KB, data=53KB
09-02 14:01:39.066 25666-25671/...r I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=59KB, data=53KB
09-02 14:01:39.066 25666-25671/... I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
09-02 14:01:46.287 25666-25671/... I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=123KB, data=94KB
09-02 14:01:46.298 25666-25671/... I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=97KB, data=59KB
09-02 14:01:53.853 25666-25671/... I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=122KB, data=90KB
09-02 14:01:53.853 25666-25671/... I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=122KB, data=90KB
09-02 14:01:53.853 25666-25671/... I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
```

Here is the code :

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));

for (int i = 0; i < IDs.size(); i++) {
    InputStream inputStream = new URL("https://awebsite/" + IDs.get(i)).openStream();
    inputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: How you find any solution seems like blocking array

Answer (score 2):

Problem "fixed", it's working on an real device but not on an emulated one.

Comment: Would be cool if someone has sufficient knowledge to let me know why.

Comment: I am working on real Android Device ( Lenovo TB-X704L having 3 GB RAM). But my apps UI stucks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found at the official documentations:

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-overview

> The Android Runtime (ART) and Dalvik virtual machine use paging and memory-mapping (mapping) to manage memory. This means that any memory an app modifies—whether by allocating new objects or touching mapped pages—remains resident in RAM and cannot be paged out. The only way to release memory from an app is to release object references that the app holds, making the memory available to the garbage collector.
>
> ## Garbage collection
>
> A managed memory environment, like the ART or
> Dalvik virtual machine keeps track of each memory allocation.

In a virtual machine, it's happening but in a Physical device, the result is different.
The Garbage collector cleans or needs to clean whatever is not in use anymore.

Comment: I am working on real Android Device ( Lenovo TB-X704L having 3 GB RAM). But my apps UI  still stucks.

Comment: May you need to see, what's happening with your app. Probably an error has made it stuck.