# Increasing code cache capacity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

The Firebase data load in the UI in API 23 but on API>=24 the logcat shows

```
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=29KB
I/art: After code cache collection, code=21KB, data=25KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
```

And the size goes on increasing but nothing loads on screen.

I have checked  [Increasing code cache capacity no ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014623/increasing-code-cache-capacity-no-ends) which says that it should work on physical device. I do not have physical device. Is there a way so that i can make it work on the emulator?